# How to fill an array of structs using a pointer while reading from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

the following has poped up while studying and I would like whether it does what it is supposed to. Let's say we have the following struct:

```
typedef struct a{
      int x;
      int y;
}a;
```

And we have a binary file where we can find info about multiple instances of the above struct, and we want to have an array of these structs and fill them one by one. Can we do the following?

```
a* aStruct= malloc(sizeof(a)*10); // aStruct[10]
a* temp;
int i = 0;
while(i < 10){
        temp = aStruct+i++;
        fread(&temp->x, sizeof(int), 1, inputFile);
        fread(&temp->y, sizeof(int), 1, inputFile);
}
```

Does the above means that in the end, the array `aStruct` will be filled with the contents from the file? If not, how can we do it?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Barmar ok thank you. Fixed. Regarding my other question?

Comment: I would use fixed-width integers (`<stdint.h>`), as you will probably know the size of each integer in the binary file, so that it isn't dependent on a specific implementation of `int`.

Comment: Also a `for` loop is more natural for this code.

Comment: While this is unlikely for the example `struct`, generalizing could lead to the possibility of padding in the struct. Then the `read` would depend on how the file was written -- the answers given so far (including OP's) would work for sequentially written members or structs with no padding. However, a struct written with padding would have to be read a `struct` at a time on an architecture with similar padding requirements, or have the padding handled explicitly.

Comment: @mpez0 True, padding should be disabled just in case. Or he could use an `intN_t[2]` instead of the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work. But there's no need for the `temp` variable.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fread(&(aStruct[i].x), sizeof aStruct[i].x, 1, inputFile);
    fread(&(aStruct[i].y), sizeof aStruct[i].y, 1, inputFile);
}
```

It's generally more idiomatic and easier to read if you use array indexing notation when you're using a pointer as an array.

I used `sizeof aStruct[i].x` rather than `sizeof(int)` so that it will automatically pick up the type from the structure declaration, rather than requiring you to keep them in sync if the structure changes.

Comment: In the sizeof, can I use int for example instead of aStruct[i].x if I am pretty sure I will find an int there, or not?

Comment: Using the variable name means that if you change the type of the variable, you don't have to remember to change what's in the `sizeof`.

Comment: I see. Thank you.